# Javascript: coding the right way (mvc?)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Im starting to code with Javascript, but i have some conceptual questions about which is the right way to code using it. In this particular moment im working on a simple html file where my friends can fill data about their grades and percentages on a table, and i'll do some calculation with that and then display them.

My questions specifically are:

- is it "better" to do calculation with data from the html table, or is
  it better to have it stored in some array/matrix that changes when
  html table is changed ( doing something like mvc style )?
- if so, is it better to re-load info from view (table) every time i do
  any calculation or there is anyway to make my inner variable to
  change when view is changed?

I ask all this because i am so used to mcv style that working javascript and html in same file, and the ways javascript is presented on tutorials confuse me about how would it be if i want to have efficient, clean code

Thanks a lot, and please be comprehensive… this is my first question on SO !

Comment: JavaScript has tons of frameworks created with these issues in mind. I'd suggest you take a look at [knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/). They offer two-way binding of your HTML view to a ViewModel without writing any boilerplate code yourself. This'll help you structure your code. They have excellent tutorials.

Comment: But others may well suggest a different framework. The question you ask is a bit broad and opinion based.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/ is another great one

Comment: `working javascript and html in same file`: you don't have to put your JS in `<script>` tags; you can write it all in a JS file and link it to your HTML file if that helps with organization. That's what I do.

Comment: i know it would sound "opinion based" but somehow it is because things can work even if they are messy and unstructured, so i want to know what would an experienced programmer do. Of course for the size of my sunday-morning project it may seem irrelevant but my question is thought to be applied in future, bigger projects. In this moment, taking into an account that js can't be in different files is a breakthrough. I think ill look for that and understand how to relate html attributes with js functions. thanks @AstroCB

Comment: No problem; what you're looking for is the [`src` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) of the `script` tag that allows you to point it to an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with MVC and would like to code JavaScript using this framework I'd look into [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) .

As far as "better" ways to write code, I'd say for the size page you're talking about it doesn't matter all that much.

If you plan on editing the data and doing calculations from it, I would store the data using an array or matrix and then build a table from that data. With AngularJS any time you make calculations and change the variables effected by those calculations, you can reference those variables int he view and it will be updated automatically.

Comment: True, but I don't think I specified that Angular IS MVC, just that he could use it ;-).

Comment: Completely correct =] It was just a sidenote/comment